# Does the Xbox 360 Slim cool better if laying horizontally?

Tags: xbox-360

The Xbox 360 Slim has cooling vents on two sides. Unfortunately one of these sides gets blocked if you keep it standing. Does that mean it will get hotter and hang up more often if the second vent is blocked?

Should I keep it laying on the bottom so both vents are open? Is this recommended?

Comment: do you mean laying horizontally when you say sleeping?

Comment: @Blake - Yes, I mean laying it flat so both vents face outward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my four days of experience with my 360 Slim, the bottom vent doesn't get very warm. If you're concerned about heat, you can construct a grate with some legs and then put your Xbox on top.